# How to make unit testing work for Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2

How can i make the unit test module work for kohana 3.3 framework? I have uncommented the unittest module in bootstrap.php. Can anyone please tell me what is the next step? I don't think i have the phpunit installed as i am on a shared server. Will the Kohana unit tests work even without phpunit kohana installed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to install phpunit. [Here is the documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/unittest/testing) about unit testing.